# DataNucleus: failed to add record to newly created table

Tags: database, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I am getting the following error:

```
12:05:59,782 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - StoreManager now created
12:07:22,801 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column "TIP.ID" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,802 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip.id] -> Column(s) [TIP.ID] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.IntegerMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.IntegerRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,822 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column ""USER".ID" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,825 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User.id] -> Column(s) ["USER".ID] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.IntegerMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.IntegerRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,828 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Table "USER" will manage the persistence of the fields for class name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User (inheritance strategy="new-table") 
12:07:22,830 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column ""USER".EMAIL" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,836 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User.email] -> Column(s) ["USER".EMAIL] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.StringMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.VarCharRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,837 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column ""USER"."NAME"" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,838 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User.name] -> Column(s) ["USER"."NAME"] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.StringMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.VarCharRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,852 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User.tips] -> Column(s) [[none]] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping" ()
12:07:22,857 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Table TIP will manage the persistence of the fields for class name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip (inheritance strategy="new-table") 
12:07:22,858 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column "TIP.CREATED" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,859 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip.created] -> Column(s) [TIP.CREATED] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.DateMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.TimestampRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,860 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column "TIP.LATITUDE" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,861 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip.latitude] -> Column(s) [TIP.LATITUDE] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.DoubleMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.DoubleRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,862 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column "TIP.LONGITUDE" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,863 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip.longitude] -> Column(s) [TIP.LONGITUDE] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.DoubleMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.DoubleRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,863 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column "TIP.TEXT" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,864 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip.text] -> Column(s) [TIP.TEXT] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.StringMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.VarCharRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,869 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Column "TIP.USER_ID" added to internal representation of table.
12:07:22,870 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Field [name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.Tip.user] -> Column(s) [TIP.USER_ID] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.PersistableMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.IntegerRDBMSMapping)
12:07:22,873 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Check of existence of "USER" returned no table
12:07:22,874 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Creating table "USER"
12:07:22,885 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - CREATE TABLE "USER"
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
    EMAIL TEXT(255) NULL,
    "NAME" TEXT(255) NULL,
     UNIQUE (EMAIL)
)
12:07:22,887 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Execution Time = 1 ms
12:07:22,890 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Check of existence of TIP returned no table
12:07:22,890 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Creating table TIP
12:07:22,899 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - CREATE TABLE TIP
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
    CREATED timestamp NULL,
    LATITUDE double NULL,
    LONGITUDE double NULL,
    TEXT TEXT(255) NULL,
    USER_ID INTEGER NULL
)
12:07:22,900 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Execution Time = 1 ms
12:07:22,924 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Creating index "TIP_N49" in catalog "" schema ""
12:07:22,925 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - CREATE INDEX TIP_N49 ON TIP (USER_ID)
12:07:22,927 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Execution Time = 0 ms
12:07:24,095 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Retrieving PreparedStatement for connection "jdbc:sqlite::memory:, UserName=null, SQLiteJDBC"
12:07:24,101 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Closing PreparedStatement "org.sqlite.PrepStmt@23461d1"
12:07:24,113 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - SELECT 'name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,U.EMAIL,U.ID,U."NAME" FROM "USER" U WHERE U.EMAIL = 
12:07:24,114 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Retrieve] - Execution Time = 1 ms
12:09:16,938 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Retrieving PreparedStatement for connection "jdbc:sqlite::memory:, UserName=null, SQLiteJDBC"
12:09:16,946 (main) WARN  [DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist] - Insert of object "name.antonsmirnov.tips.db.User@55291cd" using statement "INSERT INTO "USER" ("NAME",EMAIL) VALUES (?,?)" failed : [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: USER)
```

Comment: Schema is created automatically using <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/> in persistence.xml

Comment: so is this "google-app-engine" or "google-cloud-sql" ? because you appear to be using SQLite not AppEngine Datastore, and you don't define if this is an embedded datastore or what ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using Sqlite database in memory. It disappears when the connection is closed. So the table has gone ...

Comment: it is done in the same db connection and connection is not closed after db table is created

Comment: I don't know DataNucleus. A quick look at the documentation tells me that it automatically opens connections and releases them after use. If you configured something special, you should probably provide some code in the question, so that someone who knows DataNucleus can help you.